# Cloud Haskell hanging forever when sending messages to ManagedProcess

Tags: haskell, cloud, distributed-computing, cloud-haskell

**The Problem**

Hello! I'm writing in Cloud Haskell a simple Server - Worker program. The problem is, that when I try to create `ManagedProcess`, after the server disovery step, my example hangs forever even while using `callTimeout` (which should break after 100 ms). The code is very simple, but I cannot find anything wrong with it.

I've posted the question on the mailing list also, but as far as I know the SO community, I canget the answer a lot faster here. If I get the answer from mailing list, I will postit here also.

**Source Code**

The `Worker.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell           #-}

module Main where

import Network.Transport     (EndPointAddress(EndPointAddress))
import Control.Distributed.Process hiding (call)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform hiding (__remoteTable)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Async
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.ManagedProcess
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Time
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Timer (sleep)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Closure (mkClosure, remotable)
import Network.Transport.TCP (createTransport, defaultTCPParameters)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Node hiding (call)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Binary (Binary) 
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)
import System.Environment    (getArgs)

import qualified Server as Server

main = do
  [host, port, serverAddr] <- getArgs

  Right transport <- createTransport host port defaultTCPParameters
  node <- newLocalNode transport initRemoteTable

  let addr = EndPointAddress (pack serverAddr)
      srvID = NodeId addr

  _ <- forkProcess node $ do
    sid <- discoverServer srvID
    liftIO $ putStrLn "x"
    liftIO $ print sid
    r <- callTimeout sid (Server.Add 5 6) 100 :: Process (Maybe Double)
    liftIO $ putStrLn "x"
    liftIO $ threadDelay (10 * 1000 * 1000)


  threadDelay (10 * 1000 * 1000)
  return ()


discoverServer srvID = do
  whereisRemoteAsync srvID "serverPID"
  reply <- expectTimeout 100 :: Process (Maybe WhereIsReply)
  case reply of
    Just (WhereIsReply _ msid) -> case msid of
      Just sid -> return sid
      Nothing  -> discoverServer srvID
    Nothing                    -> discoverServer srvID
```

The `Server.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell           #-}

module Server where

import Control.Distributed.Process hiding (call)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform hiding (__remoteTable)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Async
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.ManagedProcess
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Time
import Control.Distributed.Process.Platform.Timer (sleep)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Closure (mkClosure, remotable)
import Network.Transport.TCP (createTransport, defaultTCPParameters)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Node hiding (call)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Binary (Binary) 
import Data.Typeable (Typeable)


data Add = Add Double Double
  deriving (Typeable, Generic)
instance Binary Add

launchServer :: Process ProcessId
launchServer = spawnLocal $ serve () (statelessInit Infinity) server >> return () where
  server = statelessProcess { apiHandlers            = [ handleCall_ (\(Add x y) -> liftIO (putStrLn "!") >> return (x + y)) ]
                            , unhandledMessagePolicy = Drop
                            }


main = do
  Right transport <- createTransport "127.0.0.1" "8080" defaultTCPParameters
  node <- newLocalNode transport initRemoteTable
  _ <- forkProcess node $ do
    self <- getSelfPid
    register "serverPID" self

    liftIO $ putStrLn "x"
    mid <- launchServer
    liftIO $ putStrLn "y"
    r <- call mid (Add 5 6) :: Process Double
    liftIO $ print r
    liftIO $ putStrLn "z"
    liftIO $ threadDelay (10 * 1000 * 1000)
    liftIO $ putStrLn "z2"

  threadDelay (10 * 1000 * 1000)
  return ()
```

We can run them as follow:

```
runhaskell Server.hs
runhaskell Worker.hs 127.0.0.2 8080 127.0.0.1:8080:0
```

**The Results**

When we run the programs, we got following results:

from Server:

```
x
y
!
11.0 -- this one shows that inside the same process we were able to use the "call" function
z
-- waiting - all the output above were tests from inside the server now it waits for external messages
```

from Worker:

```
x
pid://127.0.0.1:8080:0:10 -- this is the process id of the server optained with whereisRemoteAsync 
-- waiting forever on the "callTimeout sid (Server.Add 5 6) 100" code!
```

As a sidenote - I've found out that, when sending messages with `send` (from `Control.Distributed.Process`) and reciving them with `expect` works. But sending them with `call` (from `Control.Distributed.Process.Platform`) and trying to recive them with `ManagedProcess` api handlers - hangs the `call` forever (even using `callTimeout`!)

Comment: Can you please post the code for the working `expect` version of `Server.hs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client is getting an exception, which you are not able to observe easily because you are running your client in a forkProcess. If you want to do that it is fine but then you need to monitor or link to that process. In this case, simply using runProcess would be much simpler. If you do that, you will see you get this exception:

```
Worker.hs: trying to call fromInteger for a TimeInterval. Cannot guess units
```

callTimeout does not take an Integer, it takes a TimeInterval which are constructed with the functions in the Time module. This is a pseudo-Num - it does not actually support fromInteger it seems. I would consider that a bug or at least bad form (in Haskell) but in any case the way to fix your code is simply

```
r <- callTimeout sid (Server.Add 5 6) (milliSeconds 100) :: Process (Maybe Double)
```

To fix the problem with the client calling into the server, you need to register the pid of the server process you spawned rather than the main process you spawn it from - i.e. change

```
self <- getSelfPid
register "serverPID" self

liftIO $ putStrLn "x"
mid <- launchServer
liftIO $ putStrLn "y"
```

to

```
mid <- launchServer
register "serverPID" mid
liftIO $ putStrLn "y"
```

Comment: You are right! It works - not completely, but the timeout works. Thank you for the hint with `runProcess`! The only thing that I don't get is why it does NOT compute anything (I'm always getting `Nothing` from the timeout call and when we try to do `r <- call sid (Server.Add 5 6) :: Process Double` the process hangs forever without getting any response. Would you be so nice and tell me why and how can I inspect such  behaviours in the future?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that as we weren't even printing output in the client. The problem is you were registering the pid of the main thread as though it were the server; you do a spawnLocal of your server and return this as "mid" - so register "serverPID" mid will fix that and then I do see the correct result in the client.

Comment: Jeremy oh right! heh, such stupid error, thank you very very much! One last question to you - do you know why this does not work on Windows? A friend of mine was trying to execute it, but he was rejected with `getAddrInfo: does not exist (error 10093)`, which according to Windows docs means: ` 10093 - Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.` when executing `createTransport "127.0.0.1" ` ? He was trying several adresses with the same error occuring.

Comment: I have not used Haskell on Windows but network-transport-tcp is just using the "network" package under the hood, so you will find references to it. You need to use the withSocketsDo function - there is an example here: https://github.com/mmizzi/learnhs/blob/master/distributed/dist2.hs

Comment: We really should make TimeInterval support fromInteger I know, just haven't got around to it!